# 14.04.3 and 15.04 installation problem: NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup- CPU

Tags: 15.04

When trying to install ubuntu (both 14.04 or 15.04) in dual boot mode with Windows 10home on a my new laptop MSI GS60 Ghost pro 4k (intel i7 6700HQ ; 16GB RAM; nvidia gtx 970M 3GB) The installation remain stuck with the following message: NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup- CPU#....

Comment: please refer [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/216959/what-does-kernelnmi-watchdog-bug-soft-lockup-followed-by-other-errors-mean)